# Producing score as a tuple together with matrix - 2048 game

Tags: python

I'm working on programming the popular 2048 game. Currently I'm writing the function that searches for possible matches in a row. Matches are when two identical elements are next to each other or are only separated by `None`. When a match is found, the match is made and the sum is placed on the left most element in the match. For example, we have this board:

```
board = [[2.0, None, 2.0, 2.0],
     [2.0, 2.0, None, None],
     [2.0, None, 2.0, 2.0],
     [2.0, None, 2.0, None]
```

]

I wrote the following code, which works correctly for the matching part. But I also want to add the score as an extra element to my tuple of lists. I have:

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(2):
        score = 0
        if (board[i][j] != None and board[i][j] == board[i][j+1]):
            board[i][j] = board[i][j] + board[i][j+1]
            board[i][j+1] = None
            score = score + board[i][j]

        if board[i][j] != board[i][j+1] and board[i][j] == board[i][j+2]:
            board[i][j] = board[i][j] + board[i][j+2]
            board[i][j+2] = None
            score = score + board[i][j]

        if board[i][j+1] != None and board[i][j+1] == board[i][j+2]:
            board[i][j+1] = board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2]
            board[i][j+2] = None
            score = score + board[i][j+1]
```

This produces the following partially correct output:

```
[[4.0, None, None, 2.0],
[4.0, None, None, None],
[4.0, None, None, 2.0],
[4.0, None, None, None]], 0)
```

But notice the score is saying `0` which is obviously false. The score should be the total sum of all the matches in each row. For example, in this case in all rows we have 4.0, so the resulting score should be 4 x 4.0 = 16.0. Help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `score` outside of the loop will stop it to reset to 0:

```
score = 0
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(2):
        if (board[i][j] != None and board[i][j] == board[i][j+1]):
            board[i][j] = board[i][j] + board[i][j+1]
            board[i][j+1] = None
            score = score + board[i][j]

        if board[i][j] != board[i][j+1] and board[i][j] == board[i][j+2]:
            board[i][j] = board[i][j] + board[i][j+2]
            board[i][j+2] = None
            score = score + board[i][j]

        if board[i][j+1] != None and board[i][j+1] == board[i][j+2]:
            board[i][j+1] = board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2]
            board[i][j+2] = None
            score = score + board[i][j+1]
```